# why am i getting 6 column 3 row matrix?

Tags: javascript

Why cant i get:

```
[[0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]] //Creates a 2-D array
```

with m rows and n columns of zeroes // Adds the m-th row into
newArray // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the
columns // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to
the array

```
function zeroArray(m, n) {
 
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      
      row.push(0);
    }
    
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Have you considered [`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) as opposed to looping and pushing?

Comment: Because you are not reseting `row` on every row.

Comment: @tadman I am new to stackoverflow can you tell me how you corrected format of my question.

Comment: Just the `edit` link at the bottom using the [formatting markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: @tadman `fill()` will cause a different problem, all the rows will be references to the same array.

Comment: @Barmar It can be used for the final leaf nodes, not the intermediate ones. Eliminates the `push(0)` jazz.

Comment: @tadman It's not as simple as that, since `fill()` won't grow an array by itself, so you can't use it to add N zeroes to the array. I had to use the `Array()` constructor to get an array of the appropriate size first in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `newArray.push(row)`, it doesn't make a copy of `row`. So every time you do this, you're pushing a reference to the same array, and all the elements of `newArray` are the same.

Change that to

```
newArray.push([...row]);
```

to make a copy of the array.

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push([...row]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Or you can simply make a new `row` array each time through the loop.

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    let row = Array(i * n);
    row.fill(0);
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: To create a shallow copy of the array, use `[...row]`. It's 2020.

Comment: Mmm I'm confused it is not suposed that when you do a shallow copy the array will mutate ?. I though that spread operator did deep copy.

Comment: It's the same as `[row[0], row[1], row[2], ...]`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use `Array.from` with a mapping callback.

```js
function zeroArray(m, n){
  return Array.from({length: m}, (_,i)=>Array((i+1)*n).fill(0));
}
console.log(zeroArray(3,2));
```